# How to update a Specific Cell in A Column

Tags: excel, vba

So I have 2 sheets in my excel book, there are columns with dates as shown here http://prntscr.com/j4931e (this is in sheet 2) for each type of attendance (eg present or absent) I type into a cell I want it to update that same cell that is part of a column B in sheet 1 http://prntscr.com/j494s2. I hope you understand what I mean. Thanks.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)        
    Worksheets(2).Range(Target.Address) = Target        
End Sub
```

Comment: Ok Just a moment please

Comment: So I have 2 sheets in my excel book, there are columns with dates as shown here http://prntscr.com/j4931e (this is in sheet 2) for each type of attendance (eg present or absent) I type into a cell I want it to update that same cell that is part of a column B in sheet 1 http://prntscr.com/j494s2. I hope you understand what I mean. Thanks.

Comment: So for example if I type in sheet 2 cell D2 the value "Absent", cell  B2 in sheet 1 would update to "Absent".

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow the logic of that. Doesn't D1 contain a date?

Comment: Sorry I meant to type D2 and B2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. There are two options as not 100% sure what you're after. The code should go in the sheet 2 module. You might want to restrict the range triggering it, e.g. columns B-F only?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   If target.column>1 then           
       Worksheets(1).Range("B" & target.row).Value = Target.Value
   End if
End Sub
```

Comment: It adds it to the right column, but not the correct cell, eg I added "Absent" to cell D2 in sheet 2 and it added "Absent" to the last cell in column B that is in sheet 1.

Comment: Did you try the second option?

Comment: Hey again, how would I want to do the same thing, but exclude any thing typed in column A in sheet 2, how would I do that. Eg anything I type in column A that is in sheet 2, should not be added to column B that is in sheet 1, because for me column A has the values of names of the people who are present or absent..@SJR

Comment: I've added a restriction to exclude column A and similar can be done for other columns or rows etc.